# What is the difference between an inverting and non-inverting MOSFET Driver?

Tags: circuit-design, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I'm looking for a High Side MOSFET Driver (have the MIC5014/15 in mind) to drive an N-Channel MOSFET, and I noticed that this IC had a Inverting and Non-Inverting variant. What is the difference between the two? Does this have to do with the Input Signal that turns ON and OFF the MOSFET?

Datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic5014.pdf

Comment: Did you see the block diagram on page 2 of the datasheet and the "only on the inverting version" text? The added inverter inverts the input signal. The input signal determines if the MOSFET is turned on or off. From the block diagram it is easy to see if a low/high at the input turns the external MOSFET on or off. Note how the MOSFET on the right (it is on the chip) will **short** the Gate-Source of the external MOSFET so it can only turn the external MOSFET **off**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about the relationship between the input and output levels.

With a non-inverting driver, if you connect a logic high to the input, the output goes high. And a low input sends the output low.

With an inverting driver, it's the opposite way round. A low input sets the output high, and vice-versa.